# Dotted line with spaces

Tags: qgis-3

I want to symbolize a line layer like this:

[image]

With three dots - empty space (not a white covering line, since i have other data underneath) - three dots.

The closest I come is using "hashed line" and rotating the hashes 90 degrees, but it does not look good, the dots are short lines (rectangles, not circles)

[image]

How can I create the symbol? Maybe using geometry generator?

Comment: maybe with SVG markers ? or even one SVG marker made of your three dots ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do that is to use a "Marker Line" symbol for your line then duplicate this symbology two time (just click on the box below the minus box) to get 3 marker line symbol then use interval and offset to get the desired effect.

Here I use a 2mm symbol with an interval of 12mm for all three marker line and I set the offset to 0, 3 and 6 respectively for the first, second and third marker line.

[image]

in similar way you could symbolise a line with any shape (square, triangle but also SVG symbol or text) in whatever combinaison you need...